# Populate DataGridView from selected XML element using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq, datagridview

I want to display list of items in datagridview of winforms. The items are from XML files that look like this..

[image: GetLotDetails.xml]

All `<Field></Field>` are needed from `<Document name="DATA">`only. I have tried using LINQ to display them but it only returns the first `<Field>` node.

The current codes that I have done:-

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("GetLotDetails.xml");
var data = doc.Descendants("Document")
           .Where(x => (String)x.Attribute("name") == "DATA");

var query = from d in data
            select new
            {
              Name = (String)d.Element("Field").Attribute("name").Value,
              Type = "String",
              Value = (String)d.Element("Field").Value,
            };
var listQ = query.ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Can somebody help me explain why other nodes under `<Document name="DATA">` not display together? What can I do to modify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ method returns only one document node. and Your LINQ query is selecting the first element attribute and value. SelectMany will help you to get the child nodes.

```
        var data = doc.Descendants("Document")
                   .Where(x => (String)x.Attribute("name") == "DATA")
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Elements("Field"));

        var query = from d in data
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = d.Attribute("name").Value,
                        Type = "String",
                        Value = d.Value,
                    };
```

Comment: I thought it only needed to specified until attribute then it will select all the child nodes. thank you very much. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listQ = query.ToList();

foreach (var item in listQ)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
}
```

Why are you assigning DataSource inside foreach loop?  This can be done outside the loop.

Comment: I already tried put it outside the loop. the output still display only first `<Field></Field>`.